# How to validate that the user can only be accessed from one computer at a time api.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, api, model-view-controller

Good Community, how can I validate that the user who tries to enter my system can only enter from 1 machine at a time if he tries to enter from another computer he must log out.

I must also validate the maximum number of users connected at the same time.

I have used spwho2 but it does not work for me, what occurs to me is to obtain the name of the machine through javascript to only allow the user to enter from a machine, but I cannot get the name of the machine in any way either, since that if I get it from C# it gets me the name of the server where it is published.

Comment: This is way to short on details. spwho2 sounds like something from SqlServer. If it is what has it todo with this? What has the MachineName todo that the user is allowed to have only one access at time. Did you miss implementing a proper Authentication and Session Handling here? Or did you go with a custom one no one knows? And what is api.net core?

Comment: If I use spwho2 to try to manage the connections to the database and with that, I can validate the number of users, but it didn't work for me. I do the user authentication by consulting the database and comparing the credentials, then I make a token which will be linked to the user. but I have no way to validate the number of users simultaneously or that the same user can enter with another computer.

Comment: It's worth considering that this is not how to solve concurrency issues. Maybe you're doing it for some other reason, but I thought I'd mention that